# Erro ao criar entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com este problema ao tentar criar o ***Entity Framework***:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:
>   'System.ArgumentException: The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty
>   or contain only white space.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String
>   parameterName)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O erro ocorre ao tentar executar esta ação, o problema esta apenas nessa tabela, ao gerar o banco sem ela, ocorre tudo normal.

Comment: Pedro, poste o parte que você esta recebendo esse erro, somente com a descrição do erro ficar difícil entender o que possar esta ocorrendo realmente.

Comment: Boa Tarde,então eu descobri que este erro esta ocorrendo por causa de uma tabela do meu banco de dados, eu gerei o banco sem esta tabela e não deu erro algum, mas ainda preciso dessa tabela pra dar continuidade, tentei fazer a mapeação manual e não estou conseguindo atualizar

Comment: Sua tabela tem PK, é composta ? isso é o que geralmente gera esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Sem o script de criação da sua tabela e pelo erro informação pelas Exception, há algum campo na sua tabela com espaço em branco no nome.